# embed-tag for images - how to use?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, bitmap, embed

I would like to know if I have to dispose an image in AS3/Flex when using the EMBED-tag:

```
[Embed(source="../../../../../assets/interface/pause/cancel_btn_off.png")]
    public static const CancelOffBtn:Class;

private var cancelOffBtn:Bitmap = new Library.CancelOffBtn();

addChild(cancelOffBtn);
```

When I addChild this class and remove it via removeChild, do I have to dispose this or is this unnecessary? I just ask because it uses the Bitmap-class and under normal circumstances you have to dispose it for the garbage collector.

Or is there another way to embed images without the Bitmap class? I just ask because I'm new to Flex and have problems embedding my stuff into my game. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dispose of the `Bitmap` by calling the `dispose()` method on the `BitmapData` and setting `cancelOffBtn` to `null`. I don't think there's a way to clear the memory of the embedded image though as it's compiled with the swf itself, but technically you shouldn't need to.

Comment: Thanks.:) That's what I wanted to hear.